# Laravel testing with phpunit does not use configured sqlite db

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I want to seperate my tests from the actual database. I configuted it following a tutorial from laracasts but it does not seem to actually use the configured stuff. This is my phpunit.xml (relevant part)

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

I noticed it will always use my actual database instead of this configured one.
I run tests by going into **vendor/bin** and executing **phpunit ../../tests** for some reason I can not figure out it won't run out of my root directory even though i ve installed phpunit globally

Answer (score 0):

I've found it myself. The problem is that I', starting from vendor/bin folder. My starting point must be the root. So I now use

**call vendor/bin/phpunit**

From my root directory